# Grep a string in an array using two inputs

Tags: arrays, ruby, grep

I need to search over an array to find out which objects contain a specific string. The method must take two inputs.

This is a one-input method that works, and returns all objects with the letter `t`:

```
def my_array_finding_method(source)
  source.grep(/t/)
end

my_array_finding_method(array)
```

This does not work:

```
def my_array_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.grep(/thing_to_find/)
end

my_array_finding_method(array, "t")
```

I must modify the second bit of code to work. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) the variable name. Otherwise, it is just interpreted as plain text.

```
source.grep(/#{thing_to_find}/)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed, and will be very helpful in the future. As this is my first question, and a very basic one, I'm sure it's clear that I'm really new to Ruby/coding.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a regular expression:

```
def my_array_finding_method(source, thing_to_find)
  source.select { |s| s.include?(thing_to_find) }
end

arr = %w| It's true that cats have nine lives. |
   #=> ["It's", "true", "that", "cats", "have", "nine", "lives."] 
my_array_finding_method(array, "t")
   #=> ["It's", "true", "that", "cats"]
```